# All longitudes experience the midday Sun. Why do all longituted experience the Midday sun?

Tags: earth-rotation, sun

Why do all longitudes experience the Midday sun?
Any other information related will do.
What is the Midday Sun?
Any other earth or planet-related information is required.
Thank you to those who have answered my question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Midday is when the sun is at the highest point in the sky for any given day. Some would sat directly overhead.

The Earth is spheroidal in shape. As the Earth spins it presents a different line of longitude to the Sun so that with each passing moment a different line of longitude has the Sun shining directly on it. When this occurs it is midday for each line of longitude.

Comment: Note that convoluted time zone definitions can skew the idea of midday.  [This article](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/china/one-time-zone.html) suggests "In Kashgar, in western Xinjiang, solar noon can be as late as at 15:10 (3:10 pm)"... stretching the idea of the midday sun

Comment: @JeopardyTempest: The trouble with China, having a similar longitudinal spread as continental USA, Canada or Australia, is that it only has one time zone. The entire country operates on Beijing time and Beijing is in the east of China.